# Choose knots in Python regression splines

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, spline

I'm trying to make a model for a very simple data set using spline regression but so far I couldn't find any Python implementation that lets me choose knots position. The picture below shows where I want to put my knot, I want my function to consist only of 2 linear regressions and nothing more.
[image]
So far I've tried `pyearth` and `scipy` splines but I couldn't find in any of them parameter responsible for setting knots position and even when I tweak other parameters I can't get result that would satisfy me.

Comment: What was the solution you settled for?

Answer (score 0):

[patsy.dmatrix](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#spline-regression) and [scipy.interpolate.splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) both have knot selection features

Comment: How can I know how many knots to choose for my spline regression? And also the position for the knots?